# Purpose of Glassfish's "generated" directory

Tags: deployment, glassfish, directory-structure

I need to better understand what goes into the "generated" directory inside a domain folder of Glassfish. I can see that deployed applications store some resource files in there, (xmls, properties, manifests...) but don't really understand why. Google was not very useful this time. Could someone point me to some relevant documentation? Thanks.

Edit: I need to know these details because i want/need to delete this folder when restarting the server.

Answer (score 5):

> > 
>
> After experimenting a bit i found that i could delete all of the
>   following directories inside the GF domain and have them created when
>   GF starts:
>
> ```
> applications
> autodeploy
> generated
> logs
> osgi-cache
> ```
>
> The first 2, of course, if you redeploy your applications. I usually
>   delete these in development after a GF crash.

To complement sebi's answer, make sure your server is stopped when you delete those directories. Doing this while it's running may damage the domain you are working with.

Answer (score 3):

After experimenting a bit i found that i could delete all of the following directories inside the GF domain and have them created when GF starts:

- applications
- autodeploy
- **generated**
- logs
- osgi-cache

The first 2, of course, if you redeploy your applications. I usually delete these in development after a GF crash.